# AWS Route 53 point domain to directory

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I am working with AWS ubuntu 16.04 and apache webserver. My root folder is /var/www/html. I need to point my primary domain to project folder /var/www/html/store.

How is it possible..??

Comment: This has nothing to do with AWS or Route53.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit you Apache config (usually something like /etc/httpd/httpd.conf or /etc/apache/httpd.conf) and restart apache (usually `service httpd restart` or `service apache2 restart`).